# Azure - How to revert Enterprise application to normal application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an application which is converted to the enterprise application on Microsoft Azure. I want to make some changes in that like changing the Redirect URL, and Exposé an API URL.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Active Directory, the application you are referring to is just a **template** to create enterprise applications (service principals) in either the same (home) tenant or in multiple tenants.

You should still have the application template for your enterprise application within your Azure AD:

> Any changes that you make to your application object are also
> reflected in its service principal object in the application's home
> tenant only (the tenant where it was registered). This means that
> deleting an application object will also delete its home tenant
> service principal object.

[Source: Consequences of modifying and deleting applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203#consequences-of-modifying-and-deleting-applications)

You can determine the related application id within the properties of the enterprise application:

[image]

Comment: I have an application, which is now converted to the Enterprise application. I want to modify its Redirect URL and Expose an API URL

Comment: I tried to give you an answer to your question. An application cannot be "converted" to an enterprise application. You can create an enterprise application (sp) from an application but you will still have the application (template)...